# PostgreSQL: how to select multiple random rows with repeating results

Tags: postgresql, random

I have a table (mytab) in my postgres database and I want to select multiple random rows from it. I can do it by executing

```
 select * from mytab offset random() * (select count(*) from mytab) limit X;
```

But my goal is to find a query that returns set containing X random rows with repeating from mytab. Is it even possible?

#### EDIT: here's some more explaination.

E.g. if mytab contains

> > #### mytab
> >
> > row1 
> >     row2 
> >     row3 
> >     row4 
> >     row5

I want to get

> > row2 - #1
> >     row3 - #2
> >     row2 - #3
> >     row4 - #4
> >     .
> >     .
> >     .
> >     .
> >     row5 - #X-3
> >     row1 - #X-2
> >     row3 - #X-1
> >     row1 - #X

Comment: What do you mean by "random number of repeated random rows"? You want your query to contain the same row repeated a random number of times?

Comment: Please clarify. Use an example to demonstrate if it's hard to put in words.

Comment: You *really* need to provide sample data (as `CREATE TABLE` and `INSERT` statements) and expected results for this one.

Comment: Should be doable with a little help from `generate_series` (http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/functions-srf.html) and some subselects / joins.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you want a random selection with replacement.  Use the random() function from a generate_series() to generate the number of random integers you want, with replacement.

Then join that to the original table after it has been decorated with row_numbers.

If you know the original table has an integer primary key which is tightly packed (which in general is not possible to know), then you could optimize this by not needing to compute row_numbers() on the fly.

```
select * from 
(select floor(random()*(select count(*) from pgbench_tellers)+1) as 
    row_number from generate_series(1,10)
) rwr 
join 
(select *, row_number() over () from pgbench_tellers) original
using (row_number) ;
```

(Using pgbench_tellers here instead of your table, because I can't test with a hypothetical table.)